# computer and User Account Migrated using ADMT but not sending mail

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2003, admt

I have successfully migrated a User and Computer account using ADMT. The user is able to login to the computer with the new account and is able to open outlook receive mail but is not able to send internal or external mail. The Exchange server is still in the Old domain. The bounce back message received was that the user doesn't have permissions to send to the recipient. When I migrated the user I did migrate the SID history so why is mail not being about to be sent? The body of the bounce back message is as follows:

Your message did not reach some or all of the intended recipients. Subject: test Sent: 1/6/2010 4:17 PM The following recipient(s) could not be reached:

User, user on 1/6/2010 4:17 PM
You do not have permission to send to this recipient. For assistance, contact your system administrator.
MSEXCH:MSExchangeIS:/DC=com/DC=DOMAIN:SERVER

Comment: Is the user having problems sending to only a particular recipient, all recipients, internal recipients only, external recipients only?

Comment: The user is unable to send at all. this included external and internal recipients.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had this very same issue - had to add the newly created account to the old account with the send as right.